# Why i can't get value form QProcess use readyReadStandardOutput signal

Tags: qt, console, qprocess

I am working with a clientupdate.exe to update my client,so there is a func "getVersion" to get the latest version number:

```
Execute::Execute(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    f=Father::GetInstance();
    ftp=new FtpProvider(this);
    connect(ftp,SIGNAL(getVersionFinished(QString)),SLOT(handGetversionFinished(QString)));
}

void Execute::getVersion()
{
    ftp->isAutoDownloadFolder=false;
    ftp->getVersion();
}
void Execute::handGetversionFinished(QString version)
{
    f->mkinfo(Q_FUNC_INFO,QString("The lasest version num is：%1").arg(version));
    QTextStream out(stdout);
    out<<version;
    std::cout<<version.data();
    std::cout.flush();
```

//***** i can get version num here.
    }

In my client program i try to get the version number; like this

```
void MainWindow::on_checkUpdateAct_triggered()
{
    QString filepath=Paths::currentExeFilePath();
    QStringList args;
    args<<"getversion"<<filepath;
    f->mkinfo(Q_FUNC_INFO,QString("start to check version"));
    connect(&reStartProcess,SIGNAL(readyRead()),SLOT(handUpdateEXEReadyRead()));
    connect(&reStartProcess,SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()),SLOT(handUpdateEXEReadyRead()));
    connect(&reStartProcess,SIGNAL(finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)),SLOT(handReStartFinished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)));
    reStartProcess.start("ClientUpdate.exe",args);
}

void MainWindow::handUpdateEXEReadyRead()
{
    QString version=reStartProcess.readAll();
    reStartProcess.terminate();
    f->mkinfo(Q_FUNC_INFO,QString("The lasest version num is：%1").arg(version));

     if(currentVersion>=version.toFloat())
     {
         f->msg->info("Update Client","Your client is the latest version");
     }
     else
     {
         if(f->msg->ask("Update Client?",QString("The latest version is:%1,Your version is：%2.\nUpdate？").arg(version).arg(currentVersion))==QMessageBox::Yes)
             sendUpdateCommand();
     }

}
```

BUT i get nothing in handUpdateEXEReadyRead func, why why why

Comment: May be you need to use `QProcess::readAllStandardOutput`?

Comment: can you post this as an answer and accept it just so people see that this question no longer needs an answer? (stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)